# Inserting multiple rows into MySQL at once

Tags: php, mysql, row

I am trying to submit a table full of information at once, and cannot find the answer. It has no problem submitting one set of information to the DB, but i need to insult between 1 and 50 of the same value at once. Here is an example:

We are recording lap times, therefore we need to be able to fill in a table on a web app, with loads of names, and event times. Therefore, we will need to add loads of SQL entries at once.

I have tried just copy and pasting the form info, but this results in a blank set of data in phpmyadmin.

Here is the code:

```
<?php


$host = "localhost";
$databasename = "pe_results";
$databaseusername = "root";
$databasepassword = "";

$conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$databaseusername", "$databasepassword"); 
mysql_select_db("$databasename", $conn); 

        if (isset($_POST['Name'])) { 
        $Name = $_POST['Name'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Short'])) { 
        $Short = $_POST['Short'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Med'])) { 
        $Med = $_POST['Med'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Long'])) { 
        $Long = $_POST['Long'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['VLong'])) { 
        $VLong = $_POST['VLong'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Extreme'])) { 
        $Extreme = $_POST['Extreme'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['LJump'])) { 
        $LJump = $_POST['LJump'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['HJump'])) { 
        $HJump = $_POST['HJump'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Shotputt'])) { 
        $Shotputt = $_POST['Shotputt'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Discuss'])) { 
        $Discuss = $_POST['Discuss'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Javelin'])) { 
        $Javelin = $_POST['Javelin'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Date'])) { 
        $Date = $_POST['Date'];
        }
        if (isset($_POST['Year'])) { 
        $Year = $_POST['Year'];
        }



           $i = count($Name);

for ($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
$n = $Name[$i];
$s = $Short[$i];
$me = $Med[$i];
$lng = $Long[$i];
$slng = $VLong[$i];
$ext = $Extreme[$i];
$ljump = $LJump[$i];
$hjump = $HJump[$i];
$shot = $Shotputt[$i];
$disc = $Discuss[$i];
$jav = $Javelin[$i];
$date = $Date[$i];
$year = $Year[$i];

//and so on with more variable...

$sql="INSERT INTO results_main (`Name`, `Short`, `Med`, `Long`, `Vlong`, `Extreme`, `LJump`, `HJump`, `Shotputt`, `Discuss`, `Javelin`, `Date`, `Year`)
            VALUES ('$n', '$s', '$me', '$lng', '$slng', '$ext', '$ljump', '$hjump', '$shot', '$disc', '$jav', '$date', '$year')";

}


    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error ());;
        if($result){
echo"<br/>Everythings been saved";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='index.php'>Back to the main page</a>";
}

else {

echo $result = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die (mysql_error ());
}

// close connection 
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Also find HTML below

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","","pe_results");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Uh oh, tell chris that " . mysqli_connect_error() . "NO DATA WILL BE SAVED";
  }
?>
    <a href="results.php"><div id="1" >Results</div></a>
    <a href="record.php"><div id="2">Record</div></a>
    <a href="overview.php"><div id="3">Overview</div></a>
    <div id="4">Blank</div>
   <form name="input_primary" action="process.php" method="post">

    <font color="#FFFFFF"><strong>Date:</strong></font><input name="Date" type="date" />

   <font color="#FFFFFF"><strong>Year:</strong></font><select name="Year">
        <option value="7">Year 7</option>
        <option value="8">Year 8</option>
        <option value="9">Year 9</option>
        <option value="10">Year 10</option>
        <option value="11">Year 11</option>
        <option value="12">Year 12</option>
        <option value="13">Year 13</option>
       </select>
       <input type="submit" value="Save results!" name="submit" />


<table width="200" border="1px solid black" id="maintab">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">100m</th>
    <th scope="col">200m</th>
    <th scope="col">400m</th>
    <th scope="col">800m</th>
    <th scope="col">1500m</th>
    <th scope="col">Long Jump</th>
    <th scope="col">High Jump</th>
    <th scope="col">Shotputt</th>
    <th scope="col">Discus</th>
    <th scope="col">Javelin</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input name="Name" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td> 
        <input name="Short" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input name="Med" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td> 
        <input name="Long" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input name="VLong" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input name="Extreme" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input name="LJump" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input name="HJump" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input name="Shotputt" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input name="Discuss" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input name="Javelin" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Do you mean you could have 50 identical values in 50 different rows?

Comment: See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/repeat.html).

Comment: nope, its a little hard to explain, the sites on a LAN otherwise id link you. Its basically like filling out an excel spreadsheet then submitting, so after an event, there would be 20 odd names, 20 odd 100m times, 20 odd 200m times etc etc.  There are no errors upon submitting and it writes to the DB, however all fields are blank.

Comment: Fresh prince, mind dumming it down / posting an example relative to my DB? My knowledge is so poor at the mo after leaving the world of php / sql for a few years

Comment: @ChrisConorDavern - aha ok. I get it, it seems like the values of the variables arent set then? What is the value of $Name`, $short etc?

Comment: im not too sure. Ill update the question with a full sample of my php. value for $Name is just a simple 20 char limit varchar, and the rest will be integers. There is no problem writing a single line from the table, however trying to do more than one line at once results in blank data being written

Comment: @ChrisConorDavern - instead of $result = mysql_query($sql); type $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error ()); Skip quotes at the db-connection part: $conn = mysql_connect($host, $databaseusername, $databasepassword);

Comment: How does the html look like? (the part where the form is)

Comment: I'm missing a closing table-tag and closing form-tag, I suppose they are there ?

Comment: Updated with HTML. Your suggestion doesnt work, it correctly writes the first row on my table but does not write anything else. Yes i may of missed a tag out because the rest of the table is the same as the first table tags

Comment: The rest of the <tr>'s are filled with the same code as you see up there

Comment: I mean </table> and </form> . Do you have that?

Comment: yes thats all there. code just truncated to not spam the question

Comment: Ok. You say my suggestion doesn't work and it only writes one row. You only have an insert-query that writes one row? insert and query-part.

Comment: I do not understand. With what data are you trying to fill up the database? Please explain in the question how you want the code to work.

Comment: as i said, imagine filling out an excel spreadsheet on a webpage a having to post all of them values at once.. i dont know how i can explain it any easier?

Comment: Your code takes all the values from the elements in the form and put them into a row in the database. That seems to be ok, but it seems that you want to add multiple rows. Where would they come from? Do you want several places where user put in values for name, short, Med etc?

Comment: oh im sorry. basically there are 20 more <tr>'s in the code. The table is 11 coulomns by 30 rows.

Comment: Do you have more than one <input name="Name" type="text" /> ? More than one <input name="Short" type="text" size="10px" /> etc in the html-form? You want to loop through these names, short etc and save all values into db. Did i understand your question then?

Comment: thats more along the lines. There is only one input, however i have copy and pasted it throughout the code, i fear this is not the correct method though and do not know the correct way of doing this

Comment: Ok I can not give you a full example, but view my answer. I would suggest reading up on arrays and loops in php.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your Question right what you wanna do is name the fields with a `[]`
So

`<select name="Year">`

Becomes

`<select name="Year[]">`

Then you'll be able to loop through the submitted values, example:

```
foreach($_POST['Year'] as $k=>$v){
 echo $v." - This is the value";
 echo $k." - This is the key";
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
(string)$insert;
if(is_array($_POST['Year'])){
    foreach($_POST['Year'] as $k=>$v){  
         $insert .= "(".$_POST['Name'][$k].", ".$_POST['Short'][$k].", ".$_POST['Med'][$k].", ".$_POST['Long'][$k].", ".$_POST['VLong'][$k].", ".$_POST['Extreme'][$k].", ".$_POST['LJump'][$k].", ".$_POST['HJump'][$k].", ".$_POST['Shotputt'][$k].", ".$_POST['Discuss'][$k].", ".$_POST['Javelin'][$k].", ".$_POST['Date'][$k].", ".$_POST['Year'][$k]."),"; 
    }
     $insert = substr_replace($insert ,0,-1);
}else{
    $insert .= "($_POST['Name'], $_POST['Short'], $_POST['Med'], $_POST['Long'], $_POST['VLong'], $_POST['Extreme'], $_POST['LJump'], $_POST['HJump'], $_POST['Shotputt'], $_POST['Discuss'], $_POST['Javelin'], $_POST['Date'], $_POST['Year'])"; 
}
$sql="INSERT INTO results_main 
(`Name`, `Short`, `Med`, `Long`, `VLong`, `Extreme`, `LJump`, `HJump`, `Shotputt`, `Discuss`, `Javelin`, `Date`, `Year`)
VALUES 
".$insert;
```

This should do the trick to get everything into only one query instead of doing multiple queries for each row

Comment: no im afraid not, the year function works absolutely fine, the issue is writing more than one row at once

Comment: That's what im saying, with my solution you can have 10000000 select, then on the server side you loop through the results. I added a sample for you to see

Comment: ok, could you help me further as to where exactly i would add this into my php? and can i just substitute "Year" for the other values? Also what are values an keys? are keys the id's for the sql db and values what i want to insert?

Comment: @ChrisConorDavern - keys are like "identifier" for elements in an array. It could be like arr[0], arr[1], arr[2] - in this case keys are 0,1 and 2. It could also be like arr['tom'], arr['jerry'], arr['fool']  - in this case keys are tom, jerry and fool.

Comment: ok so could you give me a full on example of how to implement this? Im not sure how the echo would come into play?

Comment: getting unexpected whitespace errors where you have put $insert .= "($_POST['Name']

Answer (score 0):

Add brackets [] to ALL your names in your html-form (where it makes sense). The bracket [] tells that elements are treated as dynamic arrays.

In your **html-form**, do something like this:

```
<form name="input_primary" action="process.php" method="post">

    <font color="#FFFFFF"><strong>Date:</strong></font><input name="Date" type="date" />
   <font color="#FFFFFF"><strong>Year:</strong></font><select name="Year">
        <option value="7">Year 7</option>
        <option value="8">Year 8</option>
        <option value="9">Year 9</option>
        <option value="10">Year 10</option>
        <option value="11">Year 11</option>
        <option value="12">Year 12</option>
        <option value="13">Year 13</option>
       </select>
       <input type="submit" value="Save results!" name="submit" />


<table width="200" border="1px solid black" id="maintab">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Name</th>
    <th scope="col">100m</th>
    <th scope="col">200m</th>
    <th scope="col">400m</th>
    <th scope="col">800m</th>
    <th scope="col">1500m</th>
    <th scope="col">Long Jump</th>
    <th scope="col">High Jump</th>
    <th scope="col">Shotputt</th>
    <th scope="col">Discus</th>
    <th scope="col">Javelin</th>
  </tr>
<?php
//Repeat element inside loop 10 times
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input name="Name[]" type="text" />
    </td>
    <td> 
        <input name="Short[]" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input name="Med[]" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td> 
        <input name="Long[]" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input name="VLong[]" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input name="Extreme[]" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input name="LJump[]" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input name="HJump[]" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input name="Shotputt[]" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input name="Discuss[]" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
    <td>
         <input name="Javelin[]" type="text" size="10px" />
    </td>
  </tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
</form>
```

And in your **PHP** code do something like this:

```
//Create initial query for sql-insert.
$sql="INSERT INTO results_main (`Name`, `Short`, `Med`, `Long`, `Vlong`, `Extreme`, `LJump`, `HJump`, `Shotputt`, `Discuss`, `Javelin`, `Date`, `Year`) VALUES ";


$date = $Date; //Do like this if date-element is only occur once (at top) (then no need for brackets)
$year = $Year; //Do like this if year-element is only occur once (at top) (then no need for brackets)

$cnt = count($Name);    
for ($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++) {
    //Use mysql_escape_string to escape strings (when needed) BEFORE adding to the $sql.
    $n = $Name[$i];
    $s = $Short[$i];
    $me = $Med[$i];
    $lng = $Long[$i];
    $slng = $VLong[$i];
    $ext = $Extreme[$i];
    $ljump = $LJump[$i];
    $hjump = $HJump[$i];
    $shot = $Shotputt[$i];
    $disc = $Discuss[$i];
    $jav = $Javelin[$i];

    //Insert each row separated with a comma
    $sql .= "('$n', '$s', '$me', '$lng', '$slng', '$ext', '$ljump', '$hjump', '$shot', '$disc', '$jav', '$date', '$year'),";
}

$useQuery = substr($sql, 0, -1); //Delete last comma
$result = mysql_query($useQuery); //Do the actual insert
```

then of course, read up on PDO instead of using mysql_query etc. Do this soon because mysql_* functions like this are deprecated and will be removed in the future. PDO is a better alternative because it's oop, it's safer and more flexible. Start from here... http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php

Comment: thanks, its late where i am so i will try this tomorrow and let you know how i get on

Comment: You're welcome! its late here also. about 2 in the morning... :-)

Comment: `name="[]"` this amongst other thing wont work. and this thing with reapplying all post variable to another var is unnecessary in this case, its a waste of memory and processing, and running a query for every row goes without saying a stupid idea since it can all be run in one, and will save computer power

Comment: Hi thanks for the support. I keep getting the following error now - - -Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\process.php on line 66 - This error repeats itself for lines 65 ,66 and 76. I have updated my question with the new code i have

Comment: @Breezer - sorry for the bracket-thing. I was tired yesterday, it's editiet now.  Yes, I know it wasn't the best solution - I was just trying to demonstrate how you loop through an array and do something with it as stated in the answer.

Comment: @ChrisConorDavern - It's undefined index because you haven't added any brackets to the names of the html elements. like <select name="Year[]", >, <input name="Name[]" type="text" />, <input name="Short[]" type="text" />, <input name="Med" type="text" /> etc

Comment: @ChrisConorDavern - I've updated this code. I guess it makes more sense now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Storing your data across multiple arrays is unsafe because its so easy to get out of order and cause errors. Instead store data into an associative array like this:

```
$people = array();
$people[] = array('Name' => $name, 'Short' => $short ....);
```

The above code creates and array of arrays and the inner arrays are associative arrays so you can use the following syntax to get the name of the first person:

$people[0]['Name'];

Everything stays together and if certain values arn't set for certain people it will not seep into the other peoples records.

I see you were using POST variables. The above associative array can be easily passed around with ajax (if thats what your using, just an option) by using json_encode and json_decode. This helps preserve data structures when your passing it through multiple languages.

Lastly to insert a large number of records I would suggest a PDO statement as one ofthe easiest and cleanest way to do this. Check out a great tutorial here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Hope this helps, good luck!